# Using Rails' partials to include different html per user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, partial-views, erb

I'm using Rails 3.2.8 and need to include or import HTML (actually ERB) files in a particular webpage depending upon the URL parameters and the logged in user account. So the imported HTML/ERB file will be different very often.

For example, I have the following code in a show.html.erb file:

```
<%= render "levels/#{@level.name}/#{@user.version}" %>
```

Is it appropriate to use partials for this purpose?  According to [the documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials), partials "are another device for breaking the rendering process into more manageable chunks." I'm using partials not to modularize the page building process, but to dynamically render different content. I'm worried about the performance consequences and side effects of what I'm doing.  Is there a better way to accomplish what I want above with Rails?

Comment: you forgot close the brackets 
<%= render "levels/#{@level.name}/#{@user.version}" %>

Comment: @Azzurrio you're right, corrected, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are a definite number of these partials (there are 3 levels and 2 versions), then it might make sense to have 6 partials that you can call.  As this increases, it would probably be better to use embedded ruby to render different html.  That is

```
<div>
  <% if user.version == 2 %>
    <!-- render some stuff -->
  <% else %>
    <p>
      <!-- some other stuff -->
    </p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

If you're worried about performance, you can use [fragment caching](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Fragments.html).  Heroku has a good  [crash course in caching](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/caching-strategies).

In short, yes, partials can be used in this way; but personally, I would try to refactor it into a small number of partials that cache blocks of code

If you have thousands of partials, I don't think there is a singular way to deal with them.  That sounds to me like it could almost be a separate application that you would want to embed in your application.  Rails solves this problem with [engines](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html).  If engines aren't an option, you could also look into [presenters](http://blog.nhocki.com/2012/01/10/simple-presenters--decorators-on-rails).

Comment: There are about 1,000 levels and very roughly 30 versions per level... so quite a few "partials".  And the partials are big, it wouldn't make sense at all to put them within the show.html.erb page.

Comment: How are you generating the partials?  That is, do you have functions that are generating these partials, or are you trying to figure out how to write all of them?

Comment: The partials are all manually designed and created.  There are different versions that are only slightly different from one another.

Comment: 30,000 manually generated partials... Wow.  If you have all the partials, then it seems that the code you proposed is the correct way of doing it.  You probably want to use caching.  I think an important question that comes up is what the best practice is for dealing with 30,000 partials in rails.  I think that is a separate, but fantastic question.  It seems like it might almost be worth it to write an engine for the chunk of code that you're talking about.  Again, that's probably a separate question

Comment: it's 1,000 manually generated partials. They're worksheets for a learning system. And they get updated...  so maybe 30 updates on average. Some users need to see older versions too. I guess the heart of my question was what the best practice for dealing with 30,000 partials in Rails is.